# Location on Earth through KML

Tags: c#, kml, google-earth

My project is based on C#.I have to display longitude and latitude on google earth for that I have used this code

```
        String filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        filename = filename + @"\latlon.kml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement docEle = doc.CreateElement("Placemark");
        doc.AppendChild(docEle);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;


        XmlElement infoEle = doc.CreateElement("LookAt");           
        XmlElement altEle = doc.CreateElement("altitude");
        XmlElement nameEle = doc.CreateElement("latitude");
        XmlElement responseEle = doc.CreateElement("longitude");

        XmlElement aEle = doc.CreateElement("altitudeMode");

        infoEle.AppendChild(nameEle);
        nameEle.InnerText = txtLongitude.Text;
        infoEle.AppendChild(responseEle);
        responseEle.InnerText = txtLatitude.Text;

        infoEle.AppendChild(altEle);
        altEle.InnerXml = "1223";
        infoEle.AppendChild(aEle);
        aEle.InnerXml = "relativeToGround";


        root.AppendChild(infoEle);
        doc.Save(filename);

        Process.Start(filename);
```

Problem is earth is reading my KML file but it's not showing perfect longitude and latitude with placemark and nearby places.I get a blurred view of earth.Please help.

Comment: It would help if you attach a sample generated KML file with notational lat/lon values.

Comment: I didn't get you.Can you please explain sample generated KML and notational lat/lon values?

Comment: Paste a sample of your KML output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate this type of output shown at the following [Link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#placemark).

I think you are missing the part relative to Point's tag inside the Placemark's tag.

If you do not want to  produce a Placemark object but a Location object you have to follow the structure specified at the following [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#location)

If you wanna to zoom-in to see the 'nearby-places' you need to specify the tag 'LookAt', and obtain something like this:

```
<LookAt>
   <longitude>YourLongitude</longitude>
   <latitude>YourLatitude</latitude>
   <altitude>YourAltitude</altitude>
   <range>YourRange</range>
   <tilt>50</tilt>
   <heading>0</heading>
</LookAt>
<Placemark>
   <Point>
     <coordinates>YourLongitude,YourLatitude,YourAltitude</coordinates>
   </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I have missed the part of point's tag.Thanks alot.

Comment: Placemark is now visible through point tag but still I didn't get nearby places.Please help

Comment: What you wanna mean with 'nearby places'? other placemarks?

Comment: like my code is this now <Placemark>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>24.9353915,67.0676333</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark> It only shows file name with placemark but not a clear image of places or anything else I only get a yellow placemark visible but I want a perfect location as we get when putting longitude and latitude at the search of google Earth.

Comment: Thanks alot for help!Still I am not getting the right output maybe because I am not doing it in right way :(

Comment: I have added the output that you need to obtain. I hope it can help.